# android - show horizontal scrollview when textview is clicked

Tags: android, horizontal-scrolling

i'm new to android. I'm developing an app. I have a `textView` as the header and a `horizontal_scroll_view` with the content. Now, when I press the `textView` I need the `horizontal_scroll_view` to popup down the header.

XML layout-

```
            <TextView
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:paddingLeft="20dp"
                android:paddingStart="20dp"
                android:onClick="DailyUseItems"
                android:clickable="true"
                android:text="Daily Use Products"
                android:textColor="#FFFFFF"
                android:textSize="24sp" />



        <HorizontalScrollView xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:background="#EEEEEE"
            android:id="@+id/daily_use_items"
            android:scrollbars="none">
        </HorizontalScrollView>
```

Comment: Post your code!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you wish to show it as popup you could make custom dialog https://developer.android.com/guide/topics/ui/dialogs.html But If you would like to make HorizontalScrollView invisible and make it visible on header click you can set in xml `android:visibility="invisible"` or `android:visibility="gone"` and then in java click listener `horizontalScrollView.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);` To make it popup/slide down the header you would need to use android animation. Here is how I would do it, based on this code https://gist.github.com/rafali/5146957:

MainActivity.class

```
public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity {

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

    final HorizontalScrollView hsc = (HorizontalScrollView) findViewById(R.id.daily_use_items);
    TextView tv = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.header);

    hsc.setAlpha(0.0f);

    tv.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View view) {
            hsc.animate().alpha(1.0f);
            ResizeAnimation resizeAnimation = new ResizeAnimation(hsc,hsc.getHeight());
            resizeAnimation.setDuration(600);
            hsc.startAnimation(resizeAnimation);
        }
    });
}
}
```

ResizeAnimation.class

```
public class ResizeAnimation extends Animation {
final int startHeight;
final int targetHeight;
View view;

public ResizeAnimation(View view, int targetHeight) {
    this.view = view;
    this.targetHeight = targetHeight;
    startHeight = 0;
}

@Override
protected void applyTransformation(float interpolatedTime, Transformation t) {
    int newHeight = (int) (startHeight + (targetHeight - startHeight) * interpolatedTime);
    view.getLayoutParams().height = newHeight;
    view.requestLayout();

}

@Override
public void initialize(int width, int height, int parentWidth, int parentHeight) {
    super.initialize(width, height, parentWidth, parentHeight);
}

@Override
public boolean willChangeBounds() {
    return true;
}
}
```

Comment: Thank you Sir. For the first time when is execute the code I forget to add `android:visibility="gone"` and `horizontalScrollView.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);` and I run the app it shows the `horizontalScrollView` and when I press the header `textView` it animates and works fine but the images inside my `horizontalScrollView` got shrinked. Later I added both the codes and I run the app but nothing happens when the `textview` is clicked... Now again I removed both the code and I run the app and my  `horizontalScrollView`  is blank... Plz help me fix this... :( :(

Comment: Sir... i have removed the resizeanimation.class and ResizeAnimation `resizeAnimation = new ResizeAnimation(hsc,hsc.getHeight());
            resizeAnimation.setDuration(600);
            hsc.startAnimation(resizeAnimation);` these codes... now its working fine... Thank you sir... :) :) :)